# Discord bot not starting properly

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, startup

Here is the error message im getting:
ECHO is on.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bot\bot\Discord Bot\aquabluebot>node.
'node.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
program or batch file.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bot\bot\Discord Bot\aquabluebot>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

Here is the code put into the start.bat:

```
@echo 

node.

pause
```

Any recommendation will be noted and tried, need serious people to help if you are able too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `node .`

```
@echo
node .
pause
```

Comment: Correct! which fixed it but then now it says Error: Incorrect login details were provided. then gives me the file path?